# RawAutocomplete not showing options

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, flutter-provider

I'm getting my RawAutocomplete options from firestore using Consumer widget of provider. I do not get any error, but no suggestion options are shown below my RawAutocomplete TextField. Could you please suggest what I'm missing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dataStructs.dart';
import 'utils.dart';

class ClientSearchOrAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController clientNameController;

  const ClientSearchOrAdd({super.key, required this.clientNameController});

  @override
  State<ClientSearchOrAdd> createState() => _ClientSearchOrAddState();
}

class _ClientSearchOrAddState extends State<ClientSearchOrAdd> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<List<User>>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, List<User> snapshot, _) {
      return RawAutocomplete<String>(
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
          return snapshot
              .where((element) => element.UserInfo.name!
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()))
              .map((e) => e.UserInfo.name!)
              .toList();
        },
        optionsViewBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected,
          Iterable<String> options,
        ) {
          print(options.map((e) => e));
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 292.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  itemCount: options.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final String option = options.elementAt(index);
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        onSelected(option);
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(option),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        fieldViewBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            TextEditingController textEditingController,
            FocusNode focusNode,
            VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted,
            ) {
          return TextFormField(
            controller: widget.clientNameController,
            inputFormatters: [FirstLetterUpperCaseFormatter()],
            decoration: Utils.textFormFieldStyle(
                labelTextStr: 'Client Name', hintTextStr: 'Enter client name'),
          );
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

User and UserInfo are my data model classes which are working fine at other places in my code.

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final UserInfo userInfo;

  User({required this.id, required this.userInfo});

  // .. other functions to convert json to instance etc.
}
```

And in parent widget I have

```
  Future<List<User>> fetchClientsFromBase() async {
    List<User> _clientList = [];

    var clientDataSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('User')
        .get();
    for (var client in clientDataSnapshot.docs) {
      _clientList.add(User.fromMap(client));
    }
    return _clientList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double verticalEdgePadding = 80.0;
    const double scrollViewPadding = 10.0;
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        FutureProvider<List<jeUserWithID>>(create: (_) => fetchClientsFromBase(), initialData: []),
      ],
      child: // .. ClientSearchOrAdd used here in a Form
    );
  }
```

Comment: Inside the builder, try to `print(snapshot)` and see if it's actually has items.

Comment: No, it does not show anything in console.

Comment: However, I tried with DropDownMenu in place of RawAutocomplete, it showed data. But I cannot use that because DropDownMenu does not have inputFormatter property

Comment: It did print this time, but it took time. I tried snapshot.length. Firstly, it gave 0, then it  gave the actual length of snapshot list. But, still it does not give anything in options even if I keep typing, erase, then re-type.

Comment: Probably, optionBuilder property of RawAutocomplete do not rebuilds or wait for snapshot data and I'm stuck with this drop down suggestion feature. Neither DropDownMenu, or Autocomplete/RawAutocomplete nor my custom dropdown widget built using Stack works :(